# Replace all instances of Integrate by NIntegrate and add a Method option

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have an analytic expression which involves several integrals

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, lb, ub}]
```

where the functions `f` and bounds `lb`, `ub` differ.

I now would like to

1. replace `Integrate` by `NIntegrate`, while leaving the arguments of `Integrate` unchanged
2. specify a specific method for numerical integration, such as `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"`

I manage to accomplish (1) by

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, lb, ub}] /. Integrate -> NIntegrate
```

but I have no clue how to do (2).

Comment: `Integrate[  f[x], {x, lb, ub}] /. (Integrate[x__] :> NIntegrate[x, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the replacement rule that Öskå already provided:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, lb, ub}] /. 
 Integrate[x__] :> NIntegrate[x, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
```

However this will throw one unnecessary error message:

> Integrate::argmu: Integrate called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected. >>

You could wrap the left-hand-side of the rule in `HoldPattern`, but instead I suggest:

```
nInt = NIntegrate[##, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"] &;

Integrate[f[x], {x, lb, ub}] /. Integrate -> nInt
```

One more detail that may be important is handing Options within the original `Integrate`.
Since the Options for `Integrate` will not be accepted by `NIntegrate` you should make sure that they are stripped.  Here is a function that does this and perform the transformation:

```
intToNInt = # /. 
    HoldPattern[Integrate[x__, OptionsPattern[]]] :> 
     NIntegrate[x, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"] &;
```

(This uses [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldPattern.html) as I mentioned earlier.)

Now:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, lb, ub}, GenerateConditions -> True, 
  PrincipalValue -> True] // intToNInt
```

> ```
> NIntegrate[f[x], {x, lb, ub}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
> ```

This still gives one error message but that is simply the result of your transformation on the given example:

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = lb is not a valid limit of integration. >>