# Automatically Switch between Integrate and NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an algorithm for which I need to compute some multidimensional 
integrals. Sometimes, Integrate works but some others Integrate just fails
to compute the integral.

A simple example:

$$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} -\frac{2 x^2 \left(e^{2 y+1}+1\right) (\text{erf}(y)+\text{erf}(y+1)) e^{-x^2-(y+1)^2}}{\pi } {\rm d}x {\rm d}y$$

Calling integrate,

```
Integrate[-((2 E^(-x^2 - (1 + y)^2) (1 + E^(1 + 2 y)) x^2 (Erf[y] + Erf[1 + y]))/\[Pi]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

yields

$$ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } -\frac{e^{-(y+1)^2} \left(e^{2 y+1}+1\right) (\text{erf}(y)+\text{erf}(y+1))}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, {\rm d}y $$

which is 0 (Interestingly, WolframAlpha indeed handles this integral, while my Mathematica does not). Now, Calling NIntegrate,

```
NIntegrate[-((2 E^(-x^2 - (1 + y)^2) (1 + E^(1 + 2 y)) x^2 (Erf[y] + 
 Erf[1 + y]))/\[Pi]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 14]
```

yields $-5.2\times 10^{-16}$ (After a bunch of warnings). I was wondering I there was any way of further calling NIntegrate whenever Integrate fails. I know that I can call

```
N[Integrate[...]]
```

but I have not figured out how to pass method options to this. I am looking for a generic solution that works for higher dimensional integrals. If it helps, my integrals all involve exponentials and 
error functions similar to that one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with quite a simple function.  Let's define a few integrands to test on

```
integrand1 = -((2 E^(-x^2 - (1 + y)^2) (1 + 
         E^(1 + 2 y)) x^2 (Erf[y] + Erf[1 + y]))/π);
integrand2 = Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
integrand3 = Sin[Sin[Sin[x]]]/x;
```

Now define the integrator you requested.  It checks whether integration has succeeded by seeing whether the result includes the symbol `Integrate`

```
int[u__] := Module[{ans},
  ans = Integrate[u];
  If[FreeQ[ans, Integrate], ans, N[ans]]]
```

Now test them

```
int[integrand1, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* 0 *)
```

[It looks like Mathematica V12 computes your integral is analytically]

Here's another case that is possible analytically

```
int[integrand2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* π *)
```

and one that isn't

```
int[integrand3, {x, -2, 2}]
(* 2.75358 *)
```

------------------**WITH OPTIONS**-------------

Here is an alternative that (I hope) supports options for both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` routing them appropriately.

```
int[u__, v___Rule] := Module[{ans},
  ans = Integrate[u, Sequence @@ FilterRules[{v}, Options[Integrate]]];
  If[FreeQ[ans, Integrate], ans, 
   NIntegrate[u, 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{v}, Options[NIntegrate]]]]]]
```

There are a lot of cases to test to prove that this works fully, so here are a few:

```
int[integrand1, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* 0 *)

int[integrand2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* π *)

int[integrand3, {x, -2, 2}]
(* 2.75358 *)

int[integrand3, {x, -2, 2}, Method -> MonteCarlo]
(* 2.74324 *)

int[1/x, {x, -3, 3}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: The OP seems to want to be able to pass `Method` options to the `NIntegrate` call.  Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for this. As @MichaelE2 mentions I do want to pass options. I have not tested it yet, but I think this can either be done by changing N[ans] by a call to NIntegrate[u,opts] with some fixed options or extending the pattern to accept options as a second argument.

Comment: @MarioE.Villanueva. I've edited to support options for both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`

Comment: Thanks, I am ready to accept the answer as this already works for me. I was wondering tho, if, for the sake of completeness the following case can be addressed: Sometimes, Integrate will do at least one of the integrals and return a simplified integral. Is there any way to use this simplified integral in NIntegrate? (e.g., the integral in my question).  In particular, can we extract the integrand and remaining independent variables/limits.

Comment: @MarioE.Villanueva I think you have all the pieces to do what you are looking for, if you think it's worthwhile

Comment: For completeness, I will add the link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55744/52918, which explains how to change Integrate by NIntegrate. Thanks for all the help!